# change text of CMFCRibbonStatusBar but first character and three dot shown (like "C...")

Tags: c++, visual-c++, user-interface, mfc, statusbar

In my project (VC++,mfc,2010) , I want change status bar text.

the variable is:

```
CMFCRibbonStatusBar  m_wndStatusBar;
```

the code is:

```
{

    CString strTitlePane1=_T(""); 
    m_wndStatusBar.AddElement(new CMFCRibbonStatusBarPane(ID_STATUSBAR_PANE1, strTitlePane1,TRUE), strTitlePane1);
    m_wndStatusBar.GetElement(0)->SetText(_T("Connecting"));

}
```

but I see in status bar : `C...`

what is my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you've created your `CMFCRibbonStatusBarPane`, you need to set the expected maximum text size by calling [`CMFCRibbonStatusBarPane::SetAlmostLargeText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984084.aspx).

For example:

```
CString strTitlePane1=_T(""); 
CMFCRibbonStatusBarPane* pPane = new CMFCRibbonStatusBarPane(ID_STATUSBAR_PANE1,
                                                  strTitlePane1,TRUE);
pPane.SetAlmostLargeText(_T("Connecting"));

m_wndStatusBar.AddElement(pPane, strTitlePane1);
m_wndStatusBar.GetElement(0)->SetText(_T("Connecting"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the specs of [CMFCRibbonStatusBarPane::SetAlmostLargeText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984084.aspx)

> The library calculates the size of text that lpszAlmostLargeText
>   specifies and resizes the pane accordingly. The text will be truncated
>   if it still does not fit in the pane.

Answer (score 1):

Consider switching to information mode, if you want to maintain the status bar text manually:

```
m_wndStatusBar.SetInformation(_T("Connecting"));
```

To switch back to automatic status messages use:

```
m_wndStatusBar.SetInformation(NULL);
```